# MYSQL to SQL 2008 migration

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, data-migration

We get a MYSQL 5.0 dataset each month (1.7gig) and I need to create a process to migrate this to a SQL Server 2008.

This seems a little harder than I first thought...

I've tried a few ways:

1. Using the Import wizard
2. Setting up a linked server

I've also tried different ways:

1. Using the [.net Framework Dataprovider for MYSQL](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/dotnet/index.html)
2. Using [MYSQL ODBC 5.1 driver](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.1.html).

If I try options 1 + 1 (Wizard, using odbc), I get "unable to retrieve column information",
Option 2 + 4, I get a message:  "Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "*server name*"."

This feels like a cache, or size issue, because if I limit the rows I return to less than 300,000 it works.  This is more annoying as the main table is over 1.2 million rows.

So my questions two parts:  Am I doing this the right or wrong way, and have I missed something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SQL Server Integration Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) to connect to the MySQL database and pull the data you need over.  The SSIS team blog has a walk-through for connecting to MySQL at [Connecting to MySQL from SSIS](http://blogs.msdn.com/mattm/archive/2008/03/03/connecting-to-mysql-from-ssis.aspx).  Once you build your SSIS package, you can re-use it each time you get a new data dump.

Comment: I found a few links like that. The problem is that they are fine for high level, but are light on, in the details. eg: I didn't get a chance to debug too deep into it, so I'm not sure if that's a problem on the SSIS side, or something about the metadata being returned by the provider.  ALSO: The ADO.Net Destination worked fine, although I had to type in the table name as the list wasn't auto-populated, and I didn't run into any problems with the simple data set I was using.  SO the author doesn't know what is going wrong and is using a simple dataset???